# C function not working properly

Tags: c

Cannot get it to calculate the sum and the difference of the two complex numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sum_diff(double *r3, double *i3, double *r4, double *i4);

int main()
{
    double r3, i3, r4, i4, s3, s4, d3, d4;

    printf("Enter r3 and i3 where r3 + i3 is the first complex number.\n");
    printf("r3 = ");
    scanf("%lf", &r3);

    printf("i3 = ");
    scanf("%lf", &i3);

    printf("Enter r4 and i4 where r4 + i4 is the second complex number.\n");
    printf("r4 = ");
    scanf("%lf", &r4);

    printf("i4 = ");
    scanf("%lf", &i4);

    sum_diff(&r3, &i3, &r4, &i4);

    printf("The sum of the two complex numbers = %.3lf + %.3lf\n.", s3, s4);
    printf("The difference of the two complex numbers = %.3lf - %.3lf\n.", d3, d4);

    return 0;
}
```

```
void sum_diff(double *r3, double *i3, double *r4, double *i4)
{
    double s3, s4, d3, d4;

    s3 = *r3 + *r4;
    s4 = *i3 + *i4;
    d3 = *r3 - *r4;
    d4 = *i3 - *i4;
}
```

Comment: Please post what you mean by "not working", or the error you get. Guessing that you are getting a compilation error.

Comment: I apologize the the vague description. So basically when I run it in CodeBlocks and it prompts me to enter the complex numbers. The sum and the differences are not being calculated. It only gives me "The sum of the two complex numbers are = 0.000 + 0.000" Is it because my reference is incorrect in the void function?

Comment: You actually *are* calculating the sum and difference... you're just not doing anything with them or passing them back to `main()`.  The `s3`, `s4`, etc. in `sum_diff()` are *not* the same variables as the ones in `main()`... they're local to the `sum_diff()` function (to each call of that function, actually).

Comment: In `main()` you are trying to print the values of `s3`, `s4`, `d3` and `d4` which you never initialized or modified by a function, because `sum_diff` doesn't know about the local variables of `main` and neither does `main` about `sum_diff`, so the only thing you're doing inside this function is changing the variables local to that function only.

Comment: Please don't delete the content of your question once it's answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the scope of the variables.
Change your function to:

```
void sum_diff(double *r3, double *i3, double *r4, double *i4,
              double *s3, double *s4, double *d3, double *d4)
{
    *s3 = *r3 + *r4;
    *s4 = *i3 + *i4;
    *d3 = *r3 - *r4;
    *d4 = *i3 - *i4;
}
```

And then call it as:

```
sum_diff(&r3, &i3, &r4, &i4, &s3, &s4, &d3, &d4);
```

Answer (score 2):

`sum_diff()` has no side effects. `s3, s4, d3, d4` are all local variables. That is, the `s3` in `main()` and the `s3` in `sum_diff()` are **two different variables**.

You're looking for something more like:

```
void sum_diff(double  r3, double  i3, double  r4, double  i4,
              double *s3, double *s4, double *d3, double *d4)
{
    *s3 = r3 + r4;
    *s4 = i3 + i4;
    *d3 = r3 - r4;
    *d4 = i3 - i4;
}
```

And you would call this as:

```
sum_diff(r3, i3, r4, i4, &s3, &s4, &d3, &d4);
```

Additionally, I **strongly recommend** some combination of listening to your compiler's warnings / upgrading your compiler / using flags to include the warning level. Your code as given produces the following for me:

```
[5:18pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] gcc -Wall blah.c
blah.c:25:69: warning: variable 's3' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
    printf("The sum of the two complex numbers = %.3lf + %.3lf\n.", s3, s4);
                                                                    ^~
blah.c:25:73: warning: variable 's4' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
    printf("The sum of the two complex numbers = %.3lf + %.3lf\n.", s3, s4);
                                                                        ^~
blah.c:26:76: warning: variable 'd3' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
    printf("The difference of the two complex numbers = %.3lf - %.3lf\n.", d3, d4);
                                                                           ^~
blah.c:26:80: warning: variable 'd4' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
    printf("The difference of the two complex numbers = %.3lf - %.3lf\n.", d3, d4);
                                                                               ^~
4 warnings generated.
```

Answer (score 0):

(This is additional information to what is provided in the other answers)

It is quite hard to read, having a function taking 8 pointers, some of which are inbound and some of which are outbound.

First of all, you should not use a pointer parameter for passing a `double` which will not be changed.  The use of pointer parameters is either so that the function can change the value, or as a hand-optimization when you don't trust the compiler to pass a large value efficiently.

Secondly, the function does two separate tasks. It would be better to have two separate functions.  Also it would be better to use the return value for the returned information, this is easier to read and more idiomatic than using an out-parameter.

So the code could be, using C's native complex number support:

```
complex double my_csum(complex double a, complex double b)
{
    return a + b;
}

complex double my_cdiff(complex double a, complex double b)
{
    return a - b;
}
```

If you don't want to use that native support (e.g. for learning reasons) then I would recommend using a struct with 2 members to represent the complex number, so that you can `return` it.